# How to restart Encore after making changes to webpack.config.js

Tags: symfony, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I'm using Symfony with Encore and after reading through [this](https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/simple-example.html) article, it says to restart encore after making changes but I can't find the command to do so. I tried setting up    nodemon to watch webpack.config.js and it throws an error

```
yarn run v1.9.4
$ nodemon --watch webpack.config.js ./node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server
[33m[nodemon] 1.18.3[39m
[33m[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`[39m
[33m[nodemon] watching: webpack.config.js[39m
[32m[nodemon] starting `node ./node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server`[39m
[31m[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...[39m
```

and

```
throw new Error(`Encore.${prop}() cannot be called yet because the runtime environment doesn't appear to be configured. Make sure you're using the encore executable or call Encore.configureRuntimeEnvironment() first if you're purposely not calling Encore directly.`);
```

I feel like there's a simple command I'm missing but I can't seem to find it. This is what I'm using in package.json

```
   "start": "nodemon --watch webpack.config.js ./node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server",
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you have the watcher watching your files you just have to terminate that process and then run the watch command again:

`yarn encore dev --watch`

Comment: Would be nice if you mention how to terminate a process. Or at least mention what kind of process is it? System process, node process? I'm still green at this.

Answer (score 1):

Extra tip on Chip Dean's answer:
To 'terminate' the running process of `encore dev --watch`, you'll need to ctrl+c